# Outputting Navigation

Tags: entries, structure, navigation, drop-down

I need some help with coding the navigation.

This is the markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a>
        <div class="drop">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">signs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">printed decals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">vehicle &amp; fleet graphics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">banners &amp; posters</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">magnetics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">vinyl graphics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">construction and job site signs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">business cards &amp; flyers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sign hardware</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">get quote</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's a sample of my entries, channels and structures: http://grab.by/Awx8

This is what I have so far, but it's not really working at all:

```
{# get menu items #}
{# {% set pageItems = craft.entries.section('services').level('<= 2') %} #}

{% set pageItems = craft.entries.level('<= 2') %}

{# Output the sub menu #}
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>

    {% nav page in pageItems %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ page.navigationUrlOverride ? page.navigationUrlOverride : page.url }}">
                {% if page.navigationTitle %}
                    {{ page.navigationTitle|nl2br }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ page.title }}
                {% endif %}
            </a>

            {% ifchildren %}
                <div class="drop">
                    <ul>
                        {% children %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">get quote</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution uses:
1. LJ Dynamic Fields Plugin
2. 1 Structure I called SiteMenu

What I did is:
1. Install LJ Dynamic Fields
2. Setup a MenuLinkPage Field of fieldType Dynamic DropDown
    - In the Drop Down Options is like this because am pulling links from entries and category

```
{% set menuIds = craft.entries.section('siteMenu').ids()%}
{% set menuIdsString = menuIds | join(', not ') %}

{ "value":"#","label":"Select Page"},
{%for category in craft.categories.limit(null) %}
      { "value":"{{category.id}}" , "label":"category-{{category.group}}--{{category.title}}"},
{%endfor%}
{%for entry in craft.entries.limit(null).id('and, not '~menuIdsString).order('type ASC')%}
      { "value":"{{ entry.id }}" , "label":"{{entry.type}} - {{ entry | raw }}"  
      }
      {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

3. Setup a SiteMenu Structure on its layout I added MenuLink Field.
4. Then added Pages I need for my Menu by selecting from MenuLinkPage field.
5. Call the menu in my _layout template like this

   ```
   {% block menu %}
   ```

   {% set pages = craft.entries.section('siteMenu').level('<=2') %}

   ```
   <ul>
   <li class="mobile-close"><a href="#close" class="mobile-menu-trigger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> close menu</a></li>
   {% cache %}  
     {% nav page in pages %}

           {% set entryId = page.menuLinkPage %}

           {% if entryId > 0 %}
             {% if craft.categories.id(entryId)|length %}
               <li><a href="{{siteUrl}}index.php/{{ craft.categories.id(entryId).first().uri }}">{{page.title}}</a>
             {% else %}
               <li><a href="{{siteUrl}}index.php/{{ craft.entries.id(entryId).first().uri }}">{{page.title}}</a>
             {% endif %}    
   {% else %}
               <li><a href="{{siteUrl}}">{{page.title}}</a>

           {% endif %}

               {% ifchildren %}
                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                       {% children %}
                   </ul>
               {% endifchildren %}
           </li>
       {% endnav %}
   ```

   {% endcache %}
       

   {% endblock menu %}


   I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am still a bit confused as to steps 3 and 4. Would you mind elaborating on those instructions?

Comment: What I meant in step:<br>3. Adding entries in SiteMenu Structure,for each page link you need to select a page you want from MenuLinkPage Dropdown. <br>4. To show menu in your layout you loop through siteMenu channel like above

Comment: Maybe I'm confused because the dropdown is empty after adding dynamic dropdown with code provided.  See screenshot: [link](http://grab.by/AxJy) and [link](http://grab.by/AxJQ). Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Hi user3038693,is your code in github? send a link I can have a look.

Comment: I have it cloned in bitbucket.  Do you have a username there? If so, let me know and I'll share repository with you. Or you can contact me here with your email...[link](https://mc2.wufoo.com/forms/contact-mc2-design/)

Comment: Repo has been shared @SilvanusMatiku